# Curlybrackets not working QWERTY (ALTGR + 7 and Ctrl Alt + 7)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

For some reason my Curly brackets wont work! I been trying different recommendations but have not come to a solution yet.

When pressing Altgr + 7 it just tabs out of the software, but without tabbing out, the software text turns gray. Same happens with Ctrl alt + 7.

I been trying different Keyboard settings QWERTY Norwegian, UK, USA and the same happens.

The only way I can get curly brackets if press Crtl + Altgr + 1234567 and than erase everything from 1 to 6 but if I do ctrl + altgr 7 it still tabs out.

System Info : 
Windows 10 64bit Home
Windows Version : 1809
OS version : 17763,737
Keyboard : Razer Huntsman Elite

Comment: There seems to be a lot of different ways to type a curly brace using Alt Gr depending on the locale - have you looked at [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#Function) for it and tried the combinations for the various locales?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yeah looking at it. And altgr 7 is the right way for me. I have the same Keyboard on my laptop Norwegian QWERTY and there Altgr 7 works just fine.